# How to expose SOAP Web Service using MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway (with Spring Integration DSL)

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I’m struggling to find good examples of `Spring Integration` using the `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway`

I put together a working sample that uses `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway` to expose an Order service, and when called it consumes an order detail service using the `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`

https://github.com/yortch/spring-integration-demo/blob/outboundgateway/services/order-flow/src/main/java/com/demo/integration/order/OrderEndpoint.java

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel= ChannelNames.ORDER_INVOCATION, outputChannel = ChannelNames.ORDER_DETAIL_REQUEST_BUILDER)
    OrderRequest getOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        return orderRequest;
    }
```

This is somehow working, however my expectation for the method below is that this should be the signature of the web service method, i.e. return an `OrderResponse` type. I had this initially working this way when I was manually building the `OrderResponse` by calling other POJOs, however I can’t figure out how to keep the original web service method signature and internally use Spring Integration for the implementation, i.e via calling a channel to do the transformation and in turn call the order detail service (using `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`).

If you know any code examples for doing this, please share. I came across this one, but this is directly building the response (without using Spring Integration channels): https://bitbucket.org/tomask79/spring-boot-webservice-integration/src/master/

Comment: Your question is not clear. Everything what you need is a `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway` `@Bean` definition and `@EnableIntegration`. However according your description it looks like you have everything on board. Please, elaborate more what doesn't work and how you would like to see it working?

Comment: I would like to preserve the signature of the web service API, i.e. getOrder method should return an OrderResponse instead of OrderRequest...
```
OrderResponse getOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        \\return OrderResponse generated via calling a Spring Integration channel
    }
```
However if I change the method signature, I can't figure out how to return the output of a Spring Integration channel that would return the OrderResponse instance

Comment: That's still unclear. You just have such a `@ServiceActivator` method and create that `OrderResponse` yourself for return. If this is the end of integration flow, that object becomes a `payload` of reply message. The `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway` will take care then about the proper marshalling for this `OrderResponse` object.

Comment: Correct, I could build `OrderResponse` directly, however I also have a `@Transformer`(https://github.com/yortch/spring-integration-demo/blob/a18974829ea4667d1f7f649db88b46bd035c5a0d/services/order-flow/src/main/java/com/demo/integration/transformer/OrderDetailTransformer.java#L24) that builds an `OrderDetailRequest` which in turn is used to call another web service using `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`. I'd like to be able to build the `OrderResponse` object by calling my @Transformer\MarshallingWebServiceOutbountGateway route. Is there a way to invoke the @Transformer programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some misunderstanding what is Spring Integration flow and how its endpoints work.

1. Three first class citizens in Spring Integration: `Message`, `Channel`, `Endpoint`
2. Endpoints are connected via channels
3. Endpoints consume messages from their input channels
4. Endpoints may produce messages as a result of their calculation into the output channels.

So, in your case you want to expose a SOAP service which is going to call internally another SOAP service.

You have started properly with the `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway`. This one, I guess, produces into its channel an `OrderRequest` object. It expects an `OrderResponse` in its `replyChannel` (explicit or temporary in headers). I'm not sure what your `getOrder()` does, but if there is yet a transformer and `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`, you need to consider to connect them all into the flow. So, I think that a result of your service, should go to the channel which is an input for the transformer. An output of this transformer should go to the `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`. And result of this gateway may go to some other transformer to build an `OrderResponse` which may just go into the reply channel of the `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway`.

If that's not what you expect as an explanation, I then will request you to rephrase your question...

Comment: That is actually what I already have in place, but what I was hoping to accomplish is to combine the `@ServiceInvocation` method and the reply channel method into one “send and receive” method so that it’s clear that the `getOrder` method takes an `OrderRequest` and returns an `OrderResponse`. It sounds like either this is not feasible or not the “right” way to do it with Spring Integration?

Comment: It can be done with the `@MessagingGateway` call from that `@ServiceActivator` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#gateway. Although it doesn't sound for me a reasonable to do that fine-graining since we can just do a normal flow with direct channels and endpoints composition.

Comment: That is what I suspected, it sounds like what I have already in place is the better way to go. Unfortunately this makes our code flow harder to follow. Thank you Artem for your input and for taking the time!